# Angular-Bootstrap-Datetimepicker issue with AM/PM

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot implement full AM/PM format for hours, there is 12:00 AM but after click on the calendar there are from 0:00 to 23:00:

[image]

Source code:

```
            <b>From</b>: <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"
            style="font-weight: bold;" ng-click="events.filter.datePicked1 = true">{{events.filter.state.dateFrom | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" ng-if="events.filter.datePicked1">
                <datetimepicker data-ng-model="events.filter.state.dateFrom"
                data-datetimepicker-config="{ minView: 'day' }"
                />
            </ul>
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"
            style="font-weight: bold;" ng-click="events.filter.datePicked1 = false">{{events.filter.state.dateFrom | date:'hh:mm a'}}</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" ng-if="!events.filter.datePicked1">
                <datetimepicker data-ng-model="events.filter.state.dateFrom"
                data-datetimepicker-config="{ minView: 'minute', startView : 'hour', minuteStep: 1 }"
                />
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time format in the display is controlled by `moment.js` - see http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/

By default, the datetimepicker uses the format for the users locale. I assume your locale uses 24 hour format since that is what is displayed. If you want the same format for all users they you can create your own locale with the format you would like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, application works on Tomcat and there are some strange behaviour. I just changed on date picker ;-)